# Editar select apresentando valor do banco e mostrando outras opções da tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, formulário

> #### Tenho a tabela que registra um usuário (gr_entidade) e que tem ligação com uma tabela de status usuário (gr_entidade_status). Estou querendo que no formulário de edição (editando_usuário.php) apresente o valor que está no banco, mas possibilite eu ver os outros itens que constam na tabela  (gr_entidade_status) para que eu possa editar.

*Obs: A conexão com o banco de dados e method post está funcionando perfeitamente.*

Abaixo é o select que pego o usuário para apresentar as informações dele

```
 $sql = " SELECT * FROM gr_entidade ent
         JOIN gr_entidade_status status on ent.id_entidade_status = status.id_entidade_status
         JOIN gr_entidade_tipo tipo on ent.id_entidade_tipo = tipo.id_entidade_tipo WHERE id_entidade =  " . $_GET['id'];
$conn = mysql_query($sql);
$usuario = mysql_fetch_array($conn);
```

Então a variável $usuario junto com o campo que defino, aparece o valor que está no banco. No caso para esse código seria `value ='<?php echo $usuario ['id_entidade_tipo'] ?>'`

Abaixo segue como está o campo do status. Nesse caso, fiz um select exclusivamente na tabela de status (gr_entidade_status) para me dar o valor do nome (status)

```
  <label class="control-label">*Staus</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="id_entidade_status">
        <?php
           $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gr_processo_status");
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                               
         ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['id_status_processo']?>"> <?php echo $row['status']?></option>
          <?php
                 }
             ?>
   </select>
```

> Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para ser executado da forma correta

Comment: Recomendo que migre para o mysqli, já que o mysql se tornou obsoleto nas versões mais novas do php: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql

Comment: Mas como eu faria utilizando a versão atual? Pois não posso ainda mudar, tenho que restruturar tudo.

Comment: Vai ficar quase a mesma coisa, são poucas as mudanças. Recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação oficial do php.

Comment: Tem uma "sopa" de letrinhas, não ficou claro o que você quer. Pelo que eu entendi você quer mostrar todos os status de processos existentes, em uma tag select do html, e depois deixar selecionado um status especifico. Só que a parte `$usuario ['id_entidade_tipo']` não parece ter relação nenhuma. Falta detalhar melhor.

Comment: Esse campo está dentro da tabela gr_entidade , que recebe o código do statuas.

Comment: Por gentileza, desconsidere esse campo com a informação tipo, considere como se fosse id_entidade_status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui executando a seguinte forma:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="id_entidade_tipo">
                                                        <?php
                                                          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gr_entidade_tipo");
                                                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                               
                                                          ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id_entidade_tipo']?>" <?php if( $usuario['id_entidade_tipo'] == $row['id_entidade_tipo']){?>selected<?php } ?>> <?php echo $row['tipo_entidade']?></option>
                                                         <?php
                                                         }
                                                         ?>
                                                    </select>
```